# Getting a meaningful String using Groovy Spring security getCurrentUser

Tags: grails, spring-security

My Code to gather a string for the current user looks like this.

```
package timetracker2

import grails.timesecurity.*
import timetracker2.TimeController

class Time {

   def springSecurityService

   int id
   Project projectname
   Date dateCreated
   Date dateWorked
   Double timeSpent
   TimeClassification classification

   String currentUser = {
      String currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
      def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
      String username = user
      return username
   }

   static constraints = {
      timeSpent blank: false
      classification blank: true
   }

   static mapping = {
      table 'Time'
      cache true
      id column: 'Time_id'
      dateCreated column: 'Date_created'
      dateWorked column: 'Date_Worked'
      timeSpent column: 'Time_Spent'
      currentUser column: 'Username'
   }
}
```

this is the string that I get out.... 
timetracker2.Time$_closure1@108115

What is up with that???? Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have tried using get authorisation as well, and I have tried to add a toString method in my person class. Alas no success.

Comment: I restored the edit since the code didn't make any sense afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect part of the problem here is that you're trying to use `springSecurityService` before it has been set. The initializer expression in the declaration

```
String currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
```

runs when the object is constructed, but the `springSecurityService` reference is null at this point as it only gets injected after the constructor has finished. You could put the code that refers to `springSecurityService` into a `beforeInsert` event instead, which would delay the call until the point where the object is first saved to the DB. And you probably want `principal.username` instead of `getCurrentUser()` (thanks to Burt Beckwith for the pointer)

```
class Time {
  def springSecurityService

  String currentUser
  // other fields...

  def beforeInsert() {
    currentUser = springSecurityService.principal.username
  }
```

Comment: Right, it has to go in `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` if the user could change when editing. But additionally `getCurrentUser()` returns the whole domain class instance; it should be just `springSecurityService.principal.username`

Comment: I am guessing I am doing something wrong here as I am now getting the following error. `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Username', table 'TimeTracker.dbo.Time'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.` definitely closer, never used the beforeInsert before as below

Comment: def beforeInsert = {
  String currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() }
 def beforeUpdate = {
  String currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() }

Comment: #1, don't use `getCurrentUser()` - it's not a String. Use `springSecurityService.principal.username`. #2, use methods not closures, i.e. `def beforeInsert() { ... }` and `def beforeUpdate() { ... }`

Comment: Same problem Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Username', table 'TimeTracker.dbo.Time'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails           def beforeInsert() {
  String currentUser =  springSecurityService.principal.username }
 def beforeUpdate() {
  String currentUser = springSecurityService.principal.username }

Comment: @user1854751 you need to remove the "String" from inside the before handlers, see my edit for a simplified example. The way you have it currently you're declaring a local variable inside the handlers, not assigning to the object's property.

Comment: CHAMPION! Thanks a lot that's been doing my head in for ages!

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the `currentUser` variable with the result of calling `toString()` on a closure which, when invoked, returns the current user.

What you want is

```
String currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
```

which initializes the `currentUser` variable with the value returned by `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`.

Comment: Tried that previously, it always results in the error as follows `could not instantiate test objecttimetracker2.Time`

Comment: Edit your question. Show the code of the Time class, the code which uses it and causes this exception, and the excat and complete exception stack trace.

Comment: As requested thanks for helping | Error 2013-02-02 14:20:44,396 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -
 Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' 
 while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; 
 nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: 
 could not instantiate test objecttimetracker2.Time
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' 
while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: 
could not instantiate test objecttimetracker2.Time